# Custom States Measurement Unit in Reporting Services Indicator

Tags: reporting-services, indicator

What should i write as a custom expression when setting the States Measurement Unit for an indicator. Usually you have just Percentage and Numeric.
I have two fields F1 and F2 in the report and i want an indicator that goes from ColorA to ColorE through colors BCD when the RATIO F1/F2 between the two fields goes from the minimum to the maximum of the values in my tablix. For instance, if the F1/F2 minimum values in the data i load is 5 and the maximum is 15, therefore when the ration F1/F2 is 10 then the indicator should appear somehow of colorC (the middle one).
I can do this when i have just one field using percentage but i can't manage to do the same if the value is given with a formula.

Answer (score 0):

It appears i solved it with a formula that spits out numbers from 0 to 100:

= 100.0 * (Fields!F1.Value/Fields!F2.Value - Min(Fields!F1.Value/Fields!F2.Value)) /( Max(Fields!F1.Value/Fields!F2.Value) - Min(Fields!F1.Value/Fields!F2.Value))

Basically it's 100 * (V - MinV)/(MaxV- MinV)  where V is the Ration I need.

Sorry for bothering, hope it helps